# open a dropdown-menu toggle on hover - knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am trying to add and close the `dropdown` on hover using `knockout` and `jquery`.

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/z0hf9sxj/)

Here is the simple HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown" data-bind="event: { mouseover: enableDetails, mouseout: disableDetails }">
        Lists
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sub List 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sub List 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally `$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();` should work when placed within the `enableDetails` method in your fiddle. But this `$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle');` seems to work. Here is the updated [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/z0hf9sxj/1/)
The dropdown function is from the bootstrap [documentation.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)